# Postgresql distinct on 1 column with highest possible second column

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-15

I have table in PostgreSQL with 2 columns:

- id
- employee_id

In this table there are some records with duplicated employee_id but always unique id. I need to get unique employee_id with highest id possible. What i want to achieve is distinct query basing on employee_id, with highest id possible. So if there are 2 records with same employee_id but one with higher id than the other, then i want to get the one with higher id.

Tried this query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (employee_id) id, employee_id
FROM table_name
ORDER BY id DESC;
```

But first of all order by needs to have the same value that distinct on, secondly i would not work in my case cause it would order records after select distinct.

Second attempt also did not result in correct records:

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT DISTINCT ON (employee_id) *
    FROM
    (
        SELECT *
        FROM table_name
        ORDER BY id DESC
    ) AS sub
) AS sub2
ORDER BY id DESC;
```

I would be very grateful for help and tips.

Comment: A [mcve] is a great start when asking for SQL assistance. Also include your current query attempt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT
   DISTINCT ON (employee_id) employee_id,
   id
FROM
   table_name
ORDER BY
   employee_id, id DESC;
```

Comment: Tried this once, ERROR:  SELECT DISTINCT ON expressions must match initial ORDER BY expressions

Comment: I edited, this should work.
Order of employee_id doesn't change anything as they are duplicates, so it will put with highest ID on top and select distinct from that.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using `groub by` and `max()` :

```
select employee_id, max(id)
from table_name
group by employee_id
order by employee_id;
```